# Ionic2 Upgrade errros

Tags: ionic2

I am upgrading my app from `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` to `Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3` using [this guide](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-rc0-2016-09-28).

My code was working in the `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` version, but since the upgrade and following all the steps in the guide, when I do `ionic serve` I get lots of errors (see below).

**Question**

My question is, is there something I am doing fundamentally wrong, and if I correct it in one place it should work, or should I look at each error individually?  Has anyone else had these sorts of issues when doing an upgrade?

**Code**

**chats.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController, AlertController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MeteorComponent } from 'angular2-meteor';
import { CalendarPipe } from 'angular2-moment';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Chat, Message } from 'api/models';
import { Chats, Messages } from 'api/collections';
import { MessagesPage } from '../messages/messages';
import { UtilityService } from '../utils/utilityService';
import { PersonModel } from '../model/personModel';
import { JobModel } from '../model/jobModel';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { JobService } from '../service/jobService';
import { PersonService } from '../service/personService';
import { ChatsStorageService } from '../chats/chatsStorageService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'chats.html'
})
export class ChatsPage extends MeteorComponent {
  public chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
  public localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
  public localChatCursor: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
  public utilityService: UtilityService = null;
  public jobService: JobService = null;
  public personService: PersonService = null;
  public personModelLoggedIn: PersonModel = null;
  public personModels: PersonModel[] = [];
  public jobModels: JobModel[] = [];
  public jobModelsForSender: JobModel[] = [];
  public personModel: PersonModel = null;
  public jobModel: JobModel = null;
  public senderId: string = null;
  public events: Events = null;
  public chatsLoading: boolean = true;
  public chatsStorageService: ChatsStorageService = null;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, utilityService: UtilityService, jobService: JobService, personService: PersonService, events: Events, chatsStorageService: ChatsStorageService) {
    super();
    this.events = events;
    this.utilityService = utilityService;
    this.jobService = jobService;
    this.personService = personService;
    this.chatsStorageService = chatsStorageService;
    this.setParams();
    this.subscribeEvents();
  }

  public subscribeEvents(): void {
    let observedPromise: Promise<string> = this.utilityService.getLocalStrorage('this.messages.subscribe');
    observedPromise.then((observed: string) => {
      if (!observed || observed != 'true') {
        this.utilityService.setLocalStrorage('this.messages.subscribe', 'true');
        this.events.subscribe('messages:update', (data) => {
          console.log('subscribeEvents: messages:update  loadChats()');
          this.loadLocal(null);
          this.loadServer(false);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  public setParams(): void {
    this.utilityService.setLocalStrorage('chats.addingNewChat', 'false');
    this.jobModel = this.navParams.get('jobModel');
    this.personModel = this.navParams.get('personModel');
    let promise: Promise<string> = this.utilityService.getLoggedInPerson();
    promise.then((data) => {
      let personModelLoggedIn: PersonModel = JSON.parse(data);
      if (personModelLoggedIn) {
        this.personModelLoggedIn = personModelLoggedIn;
        this.senderId = 'P' + this.personModelLoggedIn.id;
        let promiseJobsForPerson: Promise<JobModel[]> = this.jobService.getJobsByPerson(personModelLoggedIn.id);
        promiseJobsForPerson.then((data) => {
          this.jobModelsForSender = data;
          this.loadChats();
        });

      } else {
        this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage, {
          fromChats: true
        });
      }
    });
  }

  findChat(senderId: string, receiverId: string): Chat {
    const chat: Chat = Chats.findOne({
      memberIds: { $all: [senderId, receiverId] }
    });
    return chat;
  }

  showMessages(chat: Chat): void {
    console.log('showMessages: ', chat);
    let data = {
      chat: chat,
      chatsStorageService: this.chatsStorageService
    }
    this.navCtrl.push(MessagesPage, data);
  }

  removeChat(chat): void {
    console.log('removeChat: ', chat);
    this.call('removeChat', this.senderId, chat._id);
    // this.localChatCollection.remove(chat);
    // this.localChatCursor = this.localChatCollection.find();
    let data = {
      chat: chat
    }
    this.events.publish('remove:chat', data);
    console.log('chatsStorageService.removeChat: ', chat._id);
    this.chatsStorageService.removeChat(chat);
    //this.loadLocal(null);
    this.loadServer(false);
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

  public loadChats(): void {
    this.loadLocal(null);
    this.loadServer(true);
  }

  public loadLocal(lastMessage: Message): void {
    Promise.all([this.chatsStorageService.refreshChats(), this.chatsStorageService.refreshMessages()]).then((data: any) => {
      let promiseLocalChats: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = null;
      if (lastMessage) {
        promiseLocalChats = this.findLocalChats(lastMessage);
      } else {
        promiseLocalChats = this.findLocalChatsWithLastMessageForChat();
      }
      promiseLocalChats.then((chatData: Mongo.Collection<Chat>) => {
        chatData.find().forEach((chat: Chat) => {
          this.addOrUpdateLocalChat(chat);
        });
        this.sortLocalChats();
      });
    });
  }

  public sortLocalChats(): void {
    this.localChatCursor = this.localChatCollection.find({}, { sort: { lastMessageCreatedAt: -1 } });
    // this.localChatCursor.fetch().forEach((chat: Chat) => {
    // });
    this.chatsLoading = false;
    console.log('==> loaded sorted local chats: ' + this.localChatCollection.find().count());
  }

  public addOrUpdateLocalChat(chat: Chat): void {
    let foundChat: Chat = this.localChatCollection.findOne({ _id: chat._id });
    if (foundChat && foundChat._id === chat._id) {
      let updatedChat: Chat = this.localChatCollection.update(
        { _id: chat._id },
        { $set: { lastMessageCreatedAt: chat.lastMessageCreatedAt, lastMessage: chat.lastMessage } }
      );
      if (updatedChat) {
        this.chatsStorageService.updateChat(updatedChat);
      }
    } else if (!foundChat) {
      let returnVal: string = this.localChatCollection.insert(chat);
    }
  }

  public loadServer(showMessage: boolean): void {
    let promiseChats: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = this.findChats();
    promiseChats.then((data: Mongo.Collection<Chat>) => {
      const recieverIds: string[] = this.chats
        .map(({memberIds}) => memberIds)
        .reduce((result, memberIds) => result.concat(memberIds), [])
        .concat(this.senderId);
      this.getMatchingData(recieverIds, showMessage);
    });
  }

  public getMatchingData(recieverIds: string[], showMessage: boolean): void {
    if (this.jobModel) {
      if (recieverIds.indexOf('J' + this.jobModel.id) < 0) {
        recieverIds.push('J' + this.jobModel.id);
      }
    }
    if (this.personModel) {
      if (recieverIds.indexOf('P' + this.personModel.id) < 0) {
        recieverIds.push('P' + this.personModel.id);
      }
    }
    recieverIds = this.removeDuplicates(recieverIds);
    let jobIds: string = '';
    let personIds: string = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < recieverIds.length; i++) {
      if (recieverIds[i] && recieverIds[i].substring(0, 1) == 'J') {
        jobIds += recieverIds[i].substring(1, recieverIds[i].length);
        jobIds += ',';
      } else if (recieverIds[i] && recieverIds[i].substring(0, 1) == 'P') {
        personIds += recieverIds[i].substring(1, recieverIds[i].length);
        personIds += ',';
      }
    }
    jobIds = jobIds.substring(0, jobIds.length - 1);
    personIds = personIds.substring(0, personIds.length - 1);

    let promisePersons: Promise<PersonModel[]> = this.personService.getPersons(personIds);
    promisePersons.then((personModels: PersonModel[]) => {
      for (var index = 0; index < personModels.length; index++) {
        this.personModels.push(personModels[index]);
      }
      let promiseJobs: Promise<JobModel[]> = this.jobService.getJobs(jobIds);
      promiseJobs.then((jobModels: JobModel[]) => {
        for (var index = 0; index < jobModels.length; index++) {
          this.jobModels.push(jobModels[index]);
        }

        if ((this.jobModels && this.jobModels.length > 0) || (this.personModels && this.personModels.length > 0)) {
          let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = this.findChats();
          promise.then((data: Mongo.Collection<Chat>) => {
            data.find().forEach((chat: Chat) => {
              this.addOrUpdateLocalChat(chat);
            });
            this.sortLocalChats();
            if (showMessage) {
              this.observeChats();
              this.addNewChatAndShowMessage(null);
            }
            this.chatsLoading = false;
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public observeChats(): void {
    let observedPromise: Promise<string> = this.utilityService.getLocalStrorage('this.chats.observe');
    observedPromise.then((observed: string) => {
      if (!observed || observed != 'true') {
        this.utilityService.setLocalStrorage('this.chats.observe', 'true');
        this.chats.observe({
          added: (chat) => this.chatAdded(chat),
          changed: (newChat, oldChat) => this.disposeChat(newChat, oldChat),
          removed: (chat) => this.disposeChat(null, chat)
        });
      }
    });
  }

  public disposeChat(newChat: Chat, oldChat: Chat): void {
    if (oldChat.receiverComp) {
      oldChat.receiverComp.stop();
    }
    if (oldChat.lastMessageComp) {
      oldChat.lastMessageComp.stop();
    }

    if (newChat && newChat != null && oldChat && oldChat != null && newChat._id === oldChat._id) {
      if ((newChat.lastMessage && oldChat.lastMessage && newChat.lastMessage._id != oldChat.lastMessage._id) || (newChat.lastMessage && oldChat.lastMessage && newChat.lastMessage.readByReceiver != oldChat.lastMessage.readByReceiver)) {
        let data = {
          chat: newChat
        }
        console.log('disposeChat', newChat, oldChat);
        this.events.publish('messages:update', data);
      }
    }
  }

  public chatAdded(chat: Chat) {
    let observedPromise: Promise<string> = this.utilityService.getLocalStrorage('chats.addingNewChat');
    observedPromise.then((addingNewChat: string) => {
      if (addingNewChat && addingNewChat === 'true') {
        console.log('chatAdded: ', chat, addingNewChat);
        this.addNewChatAndShowMessage(chat);
      }
    });

  }

  public addNewChatAndShowMessage(chat: Chat) {
    this.utilityService.setLocalStrorage('chats.addingNewChat', 'true');
    if (this.jobModel) {
      let jobId: string = 'J' + this.jobModel.id;
      if (!chat || chat === null) {
        chat = this.findChatAgain(this.senderId, jobId);
      }
      if (!chat || chat === null) {
        this.addChat(jobId).then(() => {
          // this.addNewChatAndShowMessage();
        });
      } else {
        chat = this.transformChat(chat);
        this.utilityService.setLocalStrorage('chats.addingNewChat', 'false');
        this.showMessages(chat);
      }
    } else if (this.personModel) {
      let personId: string = 'P' + this.personModel.id;
      if (!chat || chat === null) {
        chat = this.findChatAgain(this.senderId, personId);
      }
      if (!chat || chat === null) {
        this.addChat(personId).then(() => {
          // this.addNewChatAndShowMessage();
        });
      } else {
        chat = this.transformChat(chat);
        this.utilityService.setLocalStrorage('chats.addingNewChat', 'false');
        this.showMessages(chat);
      }
    }
  }

  public findChatAgain(senderId: string, preJobId: string): Chat {
    let chat: Chat = this.findChat(this.senderId, preJobId);
    return chat;
  }

  public addChat(userId: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.call('addChat', this.senderId, userId, (e: Error) => {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss().then(() => {
        if (e) {
          console.log('Error adding chat', e, userId);
          return this.doAlert(e);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public transformChat(chat): Chat {
    try {
      const receiverId = chat.memberIds.find(memberId => memberId != this.senderId);
      let profileName: string = null;
      let profileSubTitle: string = null;
      let profilePicture: string = null;

      for (let i = 0; i < this.jobModels.length; i++) {
        if (receiverId == 'J' + this.jobModels[i].id) {
          profileName = this.jobModels[i].person.firstName + ' ' + this.jobModels[i].person.lastName;
          profileSubTitle = this.jobModels[i].jobTitle;
          if (this.jobModels[i].avatar && this.jobModels[i].avatar != null) {
            profilePicture = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(this.jobModels[i].avatar));
          }
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < this.personModels.length; i++) {
        if (receiverId == 'P' + this.personModels[i].id) {
          if (!profileName || profileName == null) {
            profileName = this.personModels[i].firstName + ' ' + this.personModels[i].lastName;
          }
          if ((!profilePicture || profilePicture == null) && this.personModels[i].avatar && this.personModels[i].avatar != null) {
            profilePicture = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(this.personModels[i].avatar));
          }
        }
      }

      if (profileName && profileName != null) {
        chat.title = profileName;
      }
      if (profileSubTitle && profileSubTitle != null) {
        chat.subTitle = profileSubTitle;
      }
      if (profilePicture && profilePicture != null) {
        chat.picture = profilePicture;
      }
      let lastMessage: Message = this.findLastMessage(chat);
      if (lastMessage) {
        chat.lastMessage = lastMessage;
        chat.lastMessageCreatedAt = lastMessage.createdAt;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error in transformChat: ' + e.message);
    }

    return chat;
  }

  public findLastMessage(chat: Chat): Message {
    return Messages.findOne({
      chatId: chat._id
    }, {
        sort: { createdAt: -1 }
      });
  }

  public findLocalChats(lastMessage: Message): Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>(resolve => {
      let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
      for (let i: number = 0; i < this.chatsStorageService.chats.length; i++) {
        let chat: Chat = this.chatsStorageService.chats[i];
        if (lastMessage && lastMessage != null && lastMessage.chatId === chat._id) {
          chat.lastMessage = lastMessage;
          chat.lastMessageCreatedAt = lastMessage.createdAt;
          localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        }
      }
      resolve(localChatCollection);
    });
    return promise;
  }

  public findLocalChatsWithLastMessageForChat(): Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>(resolve => {
      let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
      let promises: Array<Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>> = [];
      for (let i: number = 0; i < this.chatsStorageService.chats.length; i++) {
        let chat: Chat = this.chatsStorageService.chats[i];
        let findLastMessageForChatPromise: Promise<Message> = this.chatsStorageService.findLastMessageForChat(chat);
        promises.push(findLastMessageForChatPromise);
        findLastMessageForChatPromise.then(function (_chat, data) {
          let message: Message = data;
          _chat.lastMessage = message;
          _chat.lastMessageCreatedAt = message.createdAt;
          localChatCollection.insert(_chat);
        }.bind(null, chat));

      };
      Promise.all(promises).then(function () { resolve(localChatCollection); });
    });
    return promise;
  }

  public showUnread(chat: Chat): boolean {
    if (chat && chat.lastMessage) {
      if (chat.lastMessage.readByReceiver === false || chat.lastMessage.readByReceiver + '' === 'false') {
        if (this.senderId != chat.lastMessage.senderId) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public findChats(): Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>(resolve => {
      let registeredIds: String[] = [this.senderId];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.jobModelsForSender.length; i++) {
        registeredIds.push('J' + this.jobModelsForSender[i].id);
      }
      this.subscribe('chats', this.senderId, registeredIds, () => {
        let chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat> = Chats.find(
          { memberIds: { $in: registeredIds } },
          {
            sort: { lastMessageCreatedAt: -1 },
            transform: this.transformChat.bind(this),
            fields: { memberIds: 1, lastMessageCreatedAt: 1 }
          }
        );
        this.chats = chats;
        console.log('==> loaded server chats: ' + this.chats.count());
        let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
        chats.forEach((chat: Chat) => {
          localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        });
        resolve(localChatCollection);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }

  public doAlert(e: Error) {
    console.error(e);
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Oops!',
      subTitle: e.message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  public removeDuplicates(arr: string[]): string[] {
    var unique: string[] = arr.filter(function (elem, index, self) {
      return index == self.indexOf(elem);
    })
    return unique;
  }
}
```

**Errors**

```
Typescript Error
Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
})
export class ChatsPage extends MeteorComponent {
  public chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
Typescript Error
Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Cursor'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
export class ChatsPage extends MeteorComponent {
  public chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
  public localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
Typescript Error
Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Collection'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
public chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
public localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
public localChatCursor: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
Typescript Error
Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
public chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
public localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
public localChatCursor: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
Typescript Error
Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Cursor'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
public localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
public localChatCursor: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
public utilityService: UtilityService = null;
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'Chat'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
  findChat(senderId: string, receiverId: string): Chat {
    const chat: Chat = Chats.findOne({
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'Chat'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
findChat(senderId: string, receiverId: string): Chat {
  const chat: Chat = Chats.findOne({
    memberIds: { $all: [senderId, receiverId] }
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'Chat'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
  showMessages(chat: Chat): void {
    console.log('showMessages: ', chat);
Typescript Error
Property 'call' does not exist on type 'ChatsPage'.
E:/Development/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/src/pages/chats/chats.ts
console.log('removeChat: ', chat);
this.call('removeChat', this.senderId, chat._id);
// this.localChatCollection.remove(chat);
...
```

**UPDATE**

In my app, I use a Meteror Chat App based on [this](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup). As a result I had a custom webpack with the `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` version. I currently don't have it with the `Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3` version.

Can/should I add it to the new version?

**webpack.config.js**

```
var camelCase = require('lodash.camelcase');
var upperFirst = require('lodash.upperfirst');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var isRelease = process.argv.indexOf('--release') > -1;

var config = module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.ts',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/www/build/js',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  externals: [
    'cordova',
    resolveExternals
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      api: __dirname + '/api/server'
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};

if (isRelease) {
  config.plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false }
    })
  ];
}

function resolveExternals(context, request, callback) {
  return meteorPack(request, callback) ||
    cordovaPlugin(request, callback) ||
    callback();
}

function cordovaPlugin(request, callback) {
  var match = request.match(/^cordova\/(.+)$/);
  var plugin = match && match[1];

  if (plugin) {
    plugin = camelCase(plugin);
    plugin = upperFirst(plugin);
    callback(null, 'window.cordova && cordova.plugins && cordova.plugins.' + plugin);
    return true;
  }
}

function meteorPack(request, callback) {
  var match = request.match(/^meteor\/(.+)$/);
  var pack = match && match[1];

  if (pack) {
    callback(null, 'window.Package && Package["' + pack + '"]');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you migrating things to the RC? Did you create a new project with RC and started moving things there, or are you just modifying the beta project directly?

Comment: The former. I created a new project and started moving my artificats into it.

Comment: One thing, I just remembered, I do have a custom webpack. I will add details above.